# Connecting to AWS IoT with Arduino Yun + GPRS

Tags: amazon-web-services, arduino, iot, arduino-yun, aws-iot

I'm just starting out with AWS IoT and Arduino and have had a look at the [SDK for the Arduino Yun on Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-arduino-yun). I have data collected by the Arduino and sensors and a GPRS shield connected to the Arduino to send this data, ideally to AWS IoT.

The information on the Github page seems to be related to WiFi? Looking at the installation instructions to set up OpenWRT. Naive question but if I want to use GPRS as my means for Internet connectivity and therefore AWS IoT connectivity, how can I proceed? I'm guessing I won't need to use MQTT as I only want to publish data, and not subscribe to any topics, therefore I can use HTTPS?

Comment: we are looking same implementation?if you find a solution can you email me? m.sahsuvaroglu@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is if you use AWS IoT Device SDK (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-device-sdk.html), which handles MQTT for you. This means you don't need to worry about the protocol to use, just call the bits you need. As long as you have internet connectivity, it doesn't matter if you go via WiFi of GPRS.